# PHP find string knowing only beginning of it

Tags: php

Hello i'm trying to find a the rest of the string knowing only the beginning of it.

Example:
I have start of string `Dude=99999`
Number 99999 changes its not always the same but word `Dude` is always the same.
So my question is how can i find the rest of the string after word `Dude...`
I know in `linux` there is something like `t*.txt` but in `php`? help please.

SHORT: find `'dude=` and read  the string until `'`

Comment: Where are you looking for this string? In an array? A text file? Database?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php might be what you want, but also possible with [simple string matching functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) if we knew more about the data and what code you've already tried.

Comment: basically the string starts 'dude=999' including ' so thats the way to capture it, but there are more of string between 'goat=999' i just need to get the line with 'dude=...'

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good match for a regex:

```
$regex = "/\'Dude=([0-9]+)\'/";
$str = "'Duck=123456' 'Chicken=982731' 'Dude=123487' 'Boat=129832'";

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

echo $matches[0][1]; // prints: 123487
```

If your input string/text has line-breaks, you will probably need additional flags for the regex matcher. But there are already questions and answers for this available, so please refer to the search.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  "str_replace()" function for this

```
echo str_replace("dude=","","dude=99999");
```

Here first parameter your fix string which would be start as above , second parameter is replacement string, which is put as empty , third parameter is your actual string

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to check all lines for different strings you can do as I have done recently:

```
// loop through all uploaded files:
for ($key = 0; $key < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $key++) {

  // make an array of lines from a single file:
  $txt_file = file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key]);

  // loop through this array, line by line:
  foreach ($txt_file as $line) {

    // if your file is not utf-8 fix the encoding:
    $line = iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $line);

    // check if this string begins with 'Dude=':
    if (substr($line, 0, strlen('Dude=')) === 'Dude=') {

      // if yes, then trim the 'Dude=' and get what's after it:
      $found_value[$key]['dude'] = trim(substr($line, strlen('Dude=')));

      // if this string begins with 'Dude=' it cannot begin with something else,
      // so we can go straight to the next cycle of the foreach loop:
      continue;

      // check if this string begins with 'Something else=':
    } elseif (substr($line, 0, strlen('SomethingElse=')) === 'SomethingElse=') {

      // if yes, then trim the 'SomethingElse=' and get what's after if:
      $found_value[$key]['something_else'] = trim(substr($line, strlen('SomethingElse=')));

      // if there's more items to find in the string use 'continue' to shorten server's work
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

I've adapted and commented it for you. Also you probably want to check if file(s) was uploaded properly, so you can use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and [`is_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

In the end you will get an array with structure like this:

```
$found_value [
  1 => array()[
    'dude' => 9999999
    'something_else' => 'hello'
  ]
  2 => array()[
    'dude' => 3765234
    'something_else' => 'hello again'
  ]
]
```